# Need help styling active link

Tags: html, css, list, navigation

If I set the styling font color in my unordered list for my navigation bar, how can I over ride that with a .class on a specific element?

For example, here's my navigation:
**Home

Services

About

Contact us**

And so I set in my CSS for the navigation font color to be #000.

Now what do I do if I want to over ride just one of the elements to be a specific color with a class? Because I try using a class on one of them, but it doesn't over ride it.

Comment: Post your CSS and HTML.

Comment: I have such a difficult time posting my code on here. Give me one minute though, I'll post it.

Answer (score 2):

If each of the elements are under their own li you can set one of those li's like this
li class="home" Home li and in css put .home {color:#000} if I read the question right this should help if not sorry I'm new to this.Sorry I would write it in code, but still have to get familiar with this site.

Comment: Welcome! Lots of people use jsfiddle or codepen to illustrate points that require   HTML, CSS, and JS, but if the answer is succinct (like yours), the format you used is totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :active [pseudo element](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp).

If your HTML is:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

You can do this with CSS:

```
nav a {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #3e82f7;
}

nav a:active {
    color: #db4437;
}

nav a:visited {
    color: #ffeb3b;
}
```

If you're trying to indicate what page the user is on, you probably want to structure your HTML along these lines:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="current-page" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And your CSS:

```
nav a {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.current-page {
    color: #3e82f7;
}
```